# What does "essentially developed the assertion that" mean?

Tags: relative-pronouns

The original text is:

> His address, delivered through an interpreter, essentially developed the assertion **that**, in Gram's words, "There is but one religion, and but one way to serve... ...".

My question is what does "that" here mean?

Comment: **That** refers to Gram's assertion. What did you think it might refer to?

Comment: **in Gram's words** is a parenthetical statement (the assertion...that there is...).  The that-clause complements **assertion**.

Comment: What is the source of this quote?  Are you sure that "Gram" is spelled correctly?  (Billy Graham is a famous American preacher.)

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be reworded like this:

> His words developed the assertion that "There is but one religion, and but one way to serve... ...".  (By the way, this quote is by Gram(?) himself.)